# Gateaux and Frechet differentiability

Tags: derivatives

Please help me to investigate Gateaux and Frechet differentiability of the functional $x \rightarrow ||x||_c$ depending on $x \in c$. The same about functionals $x \rightarrow ||x||_{c_0},\ x \in c_0$ and $x \rightarrow ||x||_{L_1[0,1]},\ x \in L_1[0,1]$.

Comment: What have you done so far?